# Delphi blur Effect using VCL

Tags: image, delphi, blur, effect, graphic

I'm implementing a custom panel blur effect. I would like to simulate a glass effect.
I found [the following code](http://delphi.xcjc.net/viewthread.php?tid=48791) in my searches:

```
function blur(source:TBitmap):TBitmap;
var
  x, y, x3:integer;
  tline, mline, bline:PByteArray;

begin

  for y := 1 to source.Height - 2 do
  begin
      tline := source.ScanLine[y-1];
      mline := source.ScanLine[y];
      bline := source.ScanLine[y+1];
      for x := 1 to source.Width - 2 do
      begin
        x3 := x*3;

          mline^[x3] :=
            (mline^[x3 - 3] + mline^[x3 + 3] +
             tline^[x3 - 3] + tline^[x3 + 3] + tline^[x3] +
             mline^[x3 - 3] + mline^[x3 + 3] + mline^[x3]) div 8;

          mline^[x3 + 1] :=
            (mline^[x3 - 2] + mline^[x*3 + 4] +
             tline^[x3 - 2] + tline^[x*3 + 4] + tline^[x3+1] +
             mline^[x3 - 2] + mline^[x*3 + 4] + mline^[x3+1]) div 8;

          mline^[x3 + 2] :=
            (mline^[x3 - 1] + mline^[x3 + 5] +
            tline^[x3 - 1] + tline^[x3 + 5] + tline^[x3+2] +
            mline^[x3 - 1] + mline^[x3 + 5] + mline^[x3+2]) div 8;
      end;
  end;
  result := source;
end;
```

The above function works fine, but since I am not the author and do not understand anything about image manipulation, I would add to this function the possibility of setting the blur level.

I also found the [following code](http://www.help.market.com.br/delphi/bitmap_-_criando_efeito_gaussi.htm), which works and is configurable, but, it is quite slow to apply.

A temporary solution I found to "configure" the blur was to adjust function to run itself recursively according to the level of blur you want. See the code snippet below:

```
function blur(source:TBitmap; nTimes: Integer = 1): TBitmap;
var
  x, y, x3, I : integer;
  tline, mline, bline: PByteArray;
begin
  if nTimes = 0 then Exit(source);

  for I := 0 to nTimes do...
```

**The question is: how to make a configurable and efficient blur effect or could anyone help me to improve the above function?**

Comment: That is all interesting to hear, but in case you have missed the point, this is a question/answer site. You do know what signifies a question, no?

Comment: @TomBrunberg a thousand apologies. I was so excited that I forgot the main one. I value this site a lot and I do everything to fulfill the requirements of a good question. I have edited the question and hope you can help me if possible.

Comment: Surely there are plenty of articles on this subject. You must have done some research.

Comment: You have code right there in front of you.  What don't you understand about what it is doing?  It's reasonably trivial to make this adjustable.  This isn't a question, it's a work request - you're asking for a deliverable.  That's not how it works here.

Comment: @J... Like I said, I do not understand anything about image manipulation at all. The only thing I understood about the function is that it uses a bitmap and manipulates line by line the pixels of these, nothing more. If you can give me a tip I'll make the change myself and post the answer so it will be useful to others.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan As you saw I did a research and even realized that nobody asked this here.

Comment: Except that you didn't really research with a view to understand. You appear to look for pre canned functions. I mean research to understand how blurring works.

Comment: @AnselmoMS  Your code above is implementing a type of [box blur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_blur) .  You can read about blur algorithms in this question : [How is Gaussian Blur Implemented?](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/39/2936)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes you are right. I do not intend to understand the operation of the effect completely at the moment since it is only a detail of my implementation. Since the function is already done, with that small detail (being configurable) I imagined that someone with knowledge compatible with the author of the function could help me to adjust it

Comment: Maybe somebody else will understand this for you, since you can't bring yourself to try. We'd have a lot more sympathy with you if you made an effort.

Answer (score 3):

This function does not work correctly, perhaps due to mistakes in copy-paste.

Blur is kind of convolution. To get value for pixel in blurred image, you have to calculate weighted sum of source pixels in some vicinity.

```
Dest[y,x] = Sum(dy=-size/2..size/2, dx=-size/2..size/2) (Src[y+dy, x+dx] * Weight[dy, dx])
```

In your case coefficients  (weights) are

```
  1/8  1/8  1/8      
  1/8  0    1/8   or 1/8 * (1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1)
  1/8  1/8  1/8
```

This is not Gaussian blur - its coefficients for 3x3 kernel are `1/16 * (1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 1)`. Note that central pixel is involved with the largest coefficient.

Moreover, code does not exploit lower scanline - the third line in every sum should use `bline`.

In general, you can calculate and use Gaussian kernel of any size (formula depending on `sigma` is described everywhere), but direct use of large-sized filter is slow. Multiple applying of small Gaussian filter to the same image is equivalent to applying of some larger filter.

For large kernel size there is fast (but more complicated) approach - fast convolution through FFT (fast Fourier transform).

Comment: If I understood correctly, is my temporary solution the most efficient?

Comment: Not the most efficient but quite reliable (depending on needed speed and blur degree).  Fast convolution is more effective for large kernel size, but requires splitting into r,g,b components..

Comment: _"This function does not work correctly, perhaps due to mistakes in copy-paste."_
does it refer to the full function code in my question?

Comment: Yes. It is not Gaussian blur. It is not symmetric blur - I have already written about `bline` - I suspect that blurred image will crawl up at every iteration